# Numba vectorize with participation of a constant

Tags: python, vectorization, numba

I have a Numba matrix on GPU device, want to replace values < 0 with a constant. How to do this with? Something like

```
import numba
from numba import cuda, void, int32, int64, float32, float64
import numpy as np

@numba.vectorize([int32[:, :](int32[:, :], int32)], '(i, j), () -> (i, j)', target='cuda')
def replace(a, c):  
    if a[i, j] < 0:
        return c
    else:
        return a[i, j]

b = np.array([-1, 1, 2, 3, -1], dtype=np.int32)
b = cuda.to_device(b)
replace(b, 100)
```

?

This produces

```
TypeError: vectorize() takes from 0 to 1 positional arguments but 2 were given
```

Another question, is it possible to implement such thing in-place?

Answer (score 0):

Hm. It works through enclosure

```
cc = self.c    # I am declaring and running it from class' method now

@numba.vectorize([int32(int32)], target='cuda')
def replace(b):  
    if b < 0:
        return cc   # Btw, direct self.c here causes error
    else:
        return b

...
```

But this means for typical call we'll need additional wrapper class or something like this...

Comment: And it takes 90 ms on Tesla T4 for 500 MB array. And 12 ms for compilation (I suppose) at each call